# NFC & iPhone: Background Reading Requires Cell Service?

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc

I have noticed that I can only read NFC tags on my iPhone when the phone is not in Airplane Mode (i.e. when cell service is on).  Note that whether or not I have cell *DATA* on does not seem to matter.  Also, this only applies to background reads -- if the NFC tag reader is activated manually, it works fine.

Can anyone explain why NFC tags don't read automatically if only wifi is on?  Or is there something I can do to adjust this? I'm running iOS 15.1, although I've noticed this in iOS 13/14 s well in the past.

I've tried searching the interwebs, but all I come up with is 0-level NFC intros.  Hoping the hive mind here can help a bit more... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background tag reading for NFC is disabled in Airplane Mode. This is addressed in Apple's article, [Adding Support for Background Tag Reading](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading) (emphasis mine):

> To avoid unintentional tag reading, the system reads tags in the
> background only when the user’s iPhone is in use. Also, be aware there
> are times when the display is on and background tag reading is
> unavailable, such as if:
>
> - The device has never been unlocked.
> - A Core NFC reader session is in progress.
> - Apple Pay Wallet is in use.
> - The camera is in use.
> - **Airplane mode is enabled.**

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly the clear statement I was trying to find.  I still think it's a dumb decision on Apple's part, and wish I could understand why they made this choice.  Given the rise of things like NFC business cards, it's easy to see a scenario where someone is on a plane and wants to scan a tag to get contact info.  Airplane mode is required, which makes the NFC business card useless.  I haven't yet a reason for this NFC restriction.